# When are localizations of Lawvere theories flat?    

Tags: ct.category-theory

Suppose we have a Lawvere theory $L$, i.e. a category with finite products and objects $[n]$ given by the natural numbers such that $[n] \cong [ 1 ]  ^n $, and localize it to a Lawvere theory $S^{-1}L$ by inverting an arrow in it (this works: one can e.g. get a small monoidal category with the arrow inverted as in [this](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/92929/localization-of-a-symmetric-monoidal-category-at-a-single-morphism) question, then make it into a category with finite products as in [this](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/92899/left-adjoint-to-the-forgetful-functor-from-finite-product-categories-to-symmetric) question).

Now I consider models in $Set$ of the theories so obtained:

The morphism $L \to S^{-1}L$ induces a forgetful functor $S^{-1}L-Alg \to L-Alg$ which has a left adjoint (given by left Kan extension). Analogously to the case of localization of rings this left adjoint preserves finite limits, if our arrow had domain and codomain $[ 1 ]$, i.e. we just inverted an operation with one input and one output. My question is this:

Does anybody know conditions under which the inversion of more general arrows also induces a finite limit preserving left adjoint? Simple examples are welcome. What about the free Lawvere theory on one operation $[n] \to [n]$ which we then invert? Most importantly: What about the free commutative such Lawvere theory?

Comment: Come on, last chance to grab that bounty :-)

Comment: The left adjoint to the faithful functor , do preserve the 
preserving-product funtors?

Comment: If your question is whether the above left Kan extension of a product preserving functor produces a product preserving functor again, the answer is yes: http://www.math.mq.edu.au/~street/MitchB.pdf